# libGDX: FrameBuffer size limit == max texture size?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, textures, framebuffer

I want to render my libGDX-game to a buffer and then render the content of the buffer to the screen.

For that I plan to use the FrameBuffer. The buffer dimensions suppose to be equal to the size of a screen. For example it can be 2048x1536 on a tablet.

Since FrameBuffer output is a texture I have some doubts. I know the majority of android devices has maximum texture size 1024x1024. Does it mean that the FrameBuffer also has this limitation?

If so, should I use 4 frame-buffers to do render in parts on a 2048x1536-tablet?

Answer (score 1):

Most (newer) android devices are 2048^2 or 4096^2 now.

I personally just assume that the screen size is not larger than the max size (on a mobile device), but you can check GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE to be sure.

Comment: I think that also older devices will handle 2048x2048. Though I would be rather careful with 4096.